# Swift Images change to wrong images while scrolling after async image loading to a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, image, uitableview, asynchronous

I'm trying to async load pictures inside my FriendsTableView (UITableView) cell. The images load fine but when I'll scroll the table the images will change a few times and wrong images are getting assigned to wrong cells.

I've tried all methods I could find in StackOverflow including adding a tag to the raw and then checking it but that didn't work. I'm also verifying the cell that should update with indexPath and check if the cell exists. So I have no idea why this is happening.

Here is my code:

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("friendCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FriendTableViewCell
        var avatar_url: NSURL
        let friend = sortedFriends[indexPath.row]

        //Style the cell image to be round
        cell.friendAvatar.layer.cornerRadius = 36
        cell.friendAvatar.layer.masksToBounds = true

        //Load friend photo asyncronisly
        avatar_url = NSURL(string: String(friend["friend_photo_url"]))!
        if avatar_url != "" {
                getDataFromUrl(avatar_url) { (data, response, error)  in
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
                        guard let data = data where error == nil else { return }
                        let thisCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
                        if (thisCell) != nil {
                            let updateCell =  thisCell as! FriendTableViewCell
                            updateCell.friendAvatar.image = UIImage(data: data)
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
        cell.friendNameLabel.text = friend["friend_name"].string
        cell.friendHealthPoints.text = String(friend["friend_health_points"])
        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because UITableView reuses cells. Loading them in this way causes the async requests to return at different time and mess up the order.

I suggest that you use some library which would make your life easier like Kingfisher. It will download and cache images for you. Also you wouldn't have to worry about async calls.

https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher

Your code with it would look something like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("friendCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FriendTableViewCell
        var avatar_url: NSURL
        let friend = sortedFriends[indexPath.row]

        //Style the cell image to be round
        cell.friendAvatar.layer.cornerRadius = 36
        cell.friendAvatar.layer.masksToBounds = true

        //Load friend photo asyncronisly
        avatar_url = NSURL(string: String(friend["friend_photo_url"]))!
        if avatar_url != "" {
            cell.friendAvatar.kf_setImageWithURL(avatar_url)
        }
        cell.friendNameLabel.text = friend["friend_name"].string
        cell.friendHealthPoints.text = String(friend["friend_health_points"])
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: I tried using AlamofireImage library that should have resolved this as well, but I couldn't get it to work, It had the same effect on the images. You mind explaining which methods should I use of the Kingfisher library?

Comment: I've added sample code for your case. This should work just fine.

Comment: how are you declaring the `imageView`?

Comment: Sorry, it's the imageView from your cell

Comment: so I just use `cell.friendAvatar` ?

Comment: friendAvatar in your case. Gonna update it right now.

Comment: king fish load images. but same image multiple time when scrolling. any solution ?

Answer (score 28):

On cellForRowAtIndexPath:

1) Assign an index value to your custom cell. For instance,

```
cell.tag = indexPath.row
```

2) On main thread, before assigning the image, check if the image belongs the corresponding cell by matching it with the tag.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   if(cell.tag == indexPath.row) {
     UIImage *tmpImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imgData];
     thumbnailImageView.image = tmpImage;
   }});
});
```

Comment: This did the trick for me, alongside setting the image view to nil in the cell class code.

Comment: Simple and effective!

Comment: How can i use this approach if using a cell subclass and setting everything there instead of on the viewcontroller ?

Comment: Although until now I considered using tags useless, this method is amazingly simple and effective. I am not loading images from web so using libraries like Kingfisher would be an overkill. Thank you!

Comment: this is the way  ;)

Answer (score 9):

**UPDATE**

There are some great open source libraries for image caching such as [KingFisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/wiki/Cheat-Sheet) and [SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage). I would recommend that you try one of them rather than writing your own implementation.

**END UPDATE**

So there are several things you need to do in order for this to work. First let's look at the caching code.

```
// Global variable or stored in a singleton / top level object (Ex: AppCoordinator, AppDelegate)
let imageCache = NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()

extension UIImageView {

    func downloadImage(from imgURL: String) -> URLSessionDataTask? {
        guard let url = URL(string: imgURL) else { return nil }

        // set initial image to nil so it doesn't use the image from a reused cell
        image = nil

        // check if the image is already in the cache
        if let imageToCache = imageCache.object(forKey: imgURL as NSString) {
            self.image = imageToCache
            return nil
        }

        // download the image asynchronously
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            if let err = error {
                print(err)
                return
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                // create UIImage
                let imageToCache = UIImage(data: data!)
                // add image to cache
                imageCache.setObject(imageToCache!, forKey: imgURL as NSString)
                self.image = imageToCache
            }
        }
        task.resume()
        return task
    }
}
```

You can use this outside of a TableView or CollectionView cell like this

```
let imageView = UIImageView()
let imageTask = imageView.downloadImage(from: "https://unsplash.com/photos/cssvEZacHvQ")
```

To use this in a TableView or CollectionView cell you'll need to reset the image to nil in `prepareForReuse` and cancel the download task. (Thanks for pointing that out [@rob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1271826/rob)

```
final class ImageCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    private var task: URLSessionDataTask?

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()

        task?.cancel()
        task = nil
        imageView.image = nil
    }

    // Called in cellForRowAt / cellForItemAt
    func configureWith(urlString: String) {
        if task == nil {
            // Ignore calls when reloading
            task = imageView.downloadImage(from: urlString)
        }
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "imageCell", for: indexPath) as! ImageCell
    cell.configureWith(urlString: "https://unsplash.com/photos/cssvEZacHvQ") // Url for indexPath
    return cell
}
```

Keep in mind that even if you use a 3rd party library you'll still want to nil out the image and cancel the task in `prepareForReuse`

Comment: Images getting replaced by other images when I scrolled, any solution?

Comment: @PankajBhardwaj - That’s because DoesData is not canceling the prior image request should the cell have been reused by the time this asynchronous image retrieval is done.

Answer (score 4):

If targeting iOS 13 or later, you can use [Combine](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine) and [`dataTaskPublisher(for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/3329708-datataskpublisher). See WWDC 2019 video [Advances in Networking, Part 1](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/712/?time=897).

The idea is to let the cell keep track of the “publisher”, and have `prepareForReuse`:

- cancel the prior image request;
- set the `image` property of the image view to `nil` (or a placeholder); and then
- start another image request.

For example:

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return objects.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        let url = ...
        cell.setImage(to: url)
        return cell
    }
}

class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var customImageView: UIImageView!

    private var subscriber: AnyCancellable?

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        subscriber?.cancel()
        customImageView?.image = nil
    }

    func setImage(to url: URL) {
        subscriber = ImageManager.shared.imagePublisher(for: url, errorImage: UIImage(systemName: "xmark.octagon"))
            .assign(to: \.customImageView.image, on: self)
    }
}
```

Where:

```
class ImageManager {
    static let shared = ImageManager()

    private init() { }

    private let session: URLSession = {
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.requestCachePolicy = .returnCacheDataElseLoad
        let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration)

        return session
    }()

    enum ImageManagerError: Error {
        case invalidResponse
    }

    func imagePublisher(for url: URL, errorImage: UIImage? = nil) -> AnyPublisher<UIImage?, Never> {
        session.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            .tryMap { data, response in
                guard
                    let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                    200..<300 ~= httpResponse.statusCode,
                    let image = UIImage(data: data)
                else {
                    throw ImageManagerError.invalidResponse
                }

                return image
            }
            .replaceError(with: errorImage)
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

---

If targeting earlier iOS versions, rather than using Combine, you can use `URLSession`, with the same idea of canceling the prior request in `prepareForReuse`:

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var customImageView: UIImageView!

    private weak var task: URLSessionTask?

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        task?.cancel()
        customImageView?.image = nil
    }

    func setImage(to url: URL) {
        task = ImageManager.shared.imageTask(for: url) { result in
            switch result {
            case .failure(let error): print(error)
            case .success(let image): self.customImageView.image = image
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where:

```
class ImageManager {
    static let shared = ImageManager()

    private init() { }

    private let session: URLSession = {
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.requestCachePolicy = .returnCacheDataElseLoad
        let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration)

        return session
    }()

    enum ImageManagerError: Error {
        case invalidResponse
    }

    @discardableResult
    func imageTask(for url: URL, completion: @escaping (Result<UIImage, Error>) -> Void) -> URLSessionTask {
        let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data else {
                DispatchQueue.main.async { completion(.failure(error!)) }
                return
            }

            guard
                let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                200..<300 ~= httpResponse.statusCode,
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
            else {
                DispatchQueue.main.async { completion(.failure(ImageManagerError.invalidResponse)) }
                return
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async { completion(.success(image)) }
        }
        task.resume()
        return task
    }
}
```

Comment: Well sorry, I retract my comment. — I still think the example in the video is shockingly bad practice. My point was merely that the image itself needs to be stored _somewhere_, not downloaded again when we scroll to the same row again, which is what the example in the video does.

Comment: Thanks for that. Yep, I agree that this approach relies upon the `URLCache` and web service with properly configured `Cache-Control` headers (which, IMHO, client apps should generally honor, and not override with their own caching). But you are certainly correct that if one has sloppily implemented image web services that don’t set `Cache-Control` headers correctly, then one can (and we both have, I’m sure) add custom caching mechanism to `ImageManager`.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the implementation there can be many things that will cause all of the answers here to not work (including mine). Checking the tag did not work for me, checking the cache neither, i have a custom Photo class that carries the full image, thumbnail and more data, so i have to take care of that too and not just prevent the image from being reused improperly. Since you will probably be assigning the images to the cell imageView after they're done downloading, you will need to **cancel the download and reset anything you need on prepareForReuse()**

Example if you're using something like SDWebImage

```
  override func prepareForReuse() {
   super.prepareForReuse() 

   self.imageView.sd_cancelCurrentImageLoad()
   self.imageView = nil 
   //Stop or reset anything else that is needed here 

}
```

If you have subclassed the imageview and handle the download yourself make sure you setup a way to cancel the download before the completion is called and call the cancel on `prepareForReuse()`

e.g.

```
imageView.cancelDownload()
```

You can cancel this from the UIViewController too. This on itself or combined with some of the answers will most likely solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I solve the problem just implementing a custom `UIImage` class and I did a `String` condition as the code below:

```
let imageCache = NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()

class CustomImageView: UIImageView {
    var imageUrlString: String?

    func downloadImageFrom(withUrl urlString : String) {
        imageUrlString = urlString

        let url = URL(string: urlString)
        self.image = nil

        if let cachedImage = imageCache.object(forKey: urlString as NSString) {
            self.image = cachedImage
            return
        }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
                return
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let image = UIImage(data: data!) {
                    imageCache.setObject(image, forKey: NSString(string: urlString))
                    if self.imageUrlString == urlString {
                        self.image = image
                    }
                }
            }
        }).resume()
    }
}
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 2):

TableView reuses cells. Try this:

```
import UIKit

class CustomViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

private var task: URLSessionDataTask?

override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    task?.cancel()
    imageView.image = nil
}

func configureWith(url string: String) {
    guard let url = URL(string: string) else { return }

    task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        if let data = data, let image = UIImage(data: data) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.imageView.image = image
            }
        }
    }
    task?.resume()
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because TableView reuses cells. In your cell class try this code:

```
class CustomViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var catImageView: UIImageView!

private var task: URLSessionDataTask?

override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    task?.cancel()
    catImageView.image = nil
}

func configureWith(url string: String) {
    guard let url = URL(string: string) else { return }

    task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        if let data = data, let image = UIImage(data: data) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.catImageView.image = image
            }
        }
    }
    task?.resume()
   } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

the Best Solution for This Problem i have is for Swift 3 or Swift 4 
Simply write these two lines

```
  cell.videoImage.image = nil

 cell.thumbnailimage.setImageWith(imageurl!)
```

Comment: can you please tell me that what exact error you are facing

Comment: The issue is that there is no `setImageWith` method. You’re clearly using some extension on `UIImageView` that is doing this asynchronous image retrieval, but this code alone is insufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3

```
  DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {() -> Void in

    if cell.tag == indexPath.row {
        var tmpImage = UIImage(data: imgData)
        thumbnailImageView.image = tmpImage
    }
})
```

Comment: Relying on cell tag numbers is not advisable because if a row is inserted or deleted, all subsequent tag numbers will be invalid (unless you reload the whole table, which is inefficient).

Answer (score 0):

I created a new UIImage variable in my model and load the image/placeholder from there when creating a new model instance. It worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is an example that using Kingfisher caching at memory and disk after downloaded.
It replace UrlSession downloading traditional and avoid re-download UIImageView after scroll down TableViewCell

https://gist.github.com/andreconghau/4c3b04205195f452800d2892e91a079a

Example Output

```
sucess
    Image Size:
    (460.0, 460.0)

    Cache:
    disk

    Source:
    network(Kingfisher.ImageResource(cacheKey: "https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/5936?v=4", downloadURL: https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/5936?v=4))

    Original source:
    network(Kingfisher.ImageResource(cacheKey: "https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/5936?v=4", downloadURL: https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/5936?v=4))
```