# My Images are not loading in the correct order

Tags: swift, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database

I have a tableview called (events) where i am pulling images from firebase and loading them, The idea is to post events and add flyer images with the event post. it works perfectly but when i close the app and reopen the images are not in the correct order and some images are on the wrong event. Any help will be greatly appreciated i am very new to coding.

```
        eventsDatabaseHandle = eventsRef?.child("Church Events").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snaphot) in
            let eventPost = snaphot.value as! [String: Any]
            var event = Event(title: eventPost["eventtitle"] as! String,
                              timestamp: eventPost["eventdate"] as! String,
                              location: eventPost["eventlocation"] as! String,
                              image: nil)

            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: eventPost["ImageUrl"] as! String)!) { data, _, error in

                if let image: UIImage = UIImage(data: data!) {
                    event.image = image
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.events.append(event)
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            }
            task.resume()

        })


}


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return events.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "events", for: indexPath) as! EventsTableViewCell
        let event = events[indexPath.row]
        cell.flyerImages.image = event.image
        cell.eventTitle.text = event.title
        cell.eventDate.text =  event.timestamp
        cell.eventLocation.text = event.location
```

Comment: You may want to try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35958896/6532217) approach

Comment: Hi @AliZahr thank you for your response, are you able to show me what that would look like with my code?

Comment: Right after you initialize the event, dont download the image, just append to the array and reload the table. In the cellForRowAtIndexPath download the image using the library explained in the answer

Comment: Hi @Ali I tried to make you recommendation work but I can’t figure it out or it’s not working. Like I said I’m really new to swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your Event object to take imageURL instead of UIImage, and try the following after download [this lightweight library](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher) which handles downloading and caching your images

```
    eventsDatabaseHandle = eventsRef?.child("Church Events").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snaphot) in
        let eventPost = snaphot.value as! [String: Any]
        var event = Event(title: eventPost["eventtitle"] as! String,
                          timestamp: eventPost["eventdate"] as! String,
                          location: eventPost["eventlocation"] as! String,
                          imageURL: eventPost["ImageUrl"])

         self.events.append(event)
    })

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "events", for: indexPath) as! EventsTableViewCell
    let event = events[indexPath.row]

    if let imgURL = URL(string:event.imageURL)
    {
        cell.flyerImages.kf.setImage(with:imgURL)
    }
    cell.eventTitle.text = event.title
    cell.eventDate.text =  event.timestamp
    cell.eventLocation.text = event.location
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! Ali it Worked!!